# How am I getting a single bit from an int?

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I understand that:

> int bit = (number >> 3) & 1;

Will give me the bit 3 places from the left, so lets say 8 is 1000 so that would be 0001.

What I don't understand is how "& 1" will remove everything but the last bit to display an output of simply "1". I know that this works, I know how to get a bit from an int but how is it the code is extracting the single bit?

Code...

```
int number = 8;
int bit = (number >> 3) & 1;
Console.WriteLine(bit);
```

Comment: @Kapol Yes, and that is the correct answer, assuming the OP meant "right" instead of "left". (Otherwise, it's not correct for the example in the question either.) 16 in binary is 10000, bit 3 counting from the right, starting at 0, is 0.

Comment: @Kapol Well, you're not wrong there, it's just that it takes the least significant bit of `number>>3`. :)

Comment: you can also just use `bit = number & 8` and get the same result.

Comment: @Georg the number portion may be variable in the live code.

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my comments, because I thought the "& 1" part was supposed to return the bit value every time (e.g. 16 >> 3 should be 1). Since this just needs to work in that specific case, then I'm OK with everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless my boolean algebra from school fails me, what's happening should be equivalent to the following:

```
              *
  1100110101101  // last bit is 1
& 0000000000001  // & 1
= 0000000000001  // = 1

              *
  1100110101100  // last bit is 0
& 0000000000001  // & 1
= 0000000000000  // = 0
```

So when you do `& 1`, what you're basically doing is to zero out all other bits except for the last one which will remain whatever it was. Or more technically speaking you do a *bitwise AND operation* between two numbers, where one of them happens to be a `1` with all leading bits set to `0`

Comment: to expand, the `&` operator here is known as a _bitwise AND_. In plain english; You get `true` (1, a set bit) if the sames bits are set in operands `a` AND `b` http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND

Comment: The purpose of my question was so I could fully understand the process of obtaining from an integer, a single bit. The code for position I understand. From your answer I now understand what "& 1" is and how it works, thanks :)

Comment: @AaronParkes Good to hear I interpreted it correctly ;)

Answer (score 0):

When u right shift 8 you get 0001
0001 & 0001 = 0001 which converted to int gives you 1.

So, when a value 0001 has been assigned to an int, it will print 1 and not 0001 or 0000 0001. All the leading zeroes will be discarded.

Comment: I didn't downvote it, but it was because you didn't answer his question. Your answer just repeats what he said he already understood.

Comment: Well, I did not know if it was so difficult to understand that an int value of 1 will print 1 and not the leading zeroes. I did mention that it the anding will give 1 and I meant that not 0001 but 1. Anyways.

Answer (score 0):

```
8      = 00001000
8 >> 1 = 00000100
8 >> 2 = 00000010
8 >> 3 = 00000001


If you use mask 1 = 000000001 then you have:
8 >> 3       = 000000001
1            = 000000001
(8 >> 3) & 1 = 000000001
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is not hard to understand.
the "& 1" operation is just set all bits of the value to the "0", except the bit, which placed in the same position as the valuable bit in the value "1"

previous operation just shifts the all bits to the right. and places the checked bit to the position which won't be setted to "0" after operation "& 1"

fo example

number is 1011101

number >> 3 makes it 0001011

but (number >> 3) & 1 makes it 0000001