# In Python, how can I convert a RGB array to binary and get the most significant bit?

Tags: python, arrays, binary, rgb, bit

Im using scipy to read a image and extract the RGB array like this

```
img_b = misc.imread('google.png')
img_b_blue = img_b[:, :, 0]
img_b_blue = img_b_blue.ravel()
```

Now I need to convert the img_b_blue array to binary and get the most significant bit.

I can convert using map:

```
img_b_blue_bin = map(bin, img_b_blue)
```

But it comes as string in the format '0b11110001'.
Theres a way to using map and convert to binary without the 'b'? And how can I get the most significant bit?

Comment: What do you mean with *binary*? Booleans I suppose since the most significant bit is either 0 or 1...

Comment: Integers are already stored as binary. There's no need to do anything to convert an integer to binary : `0b11110001` is valid Python for `241`, and you can apply bitwise arithmetic directly to the integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the most significant bit by right-shifting 7 bits. The result is an integer array.

```
img_b_blue_bin = img_b_blue >> 7
```

Alternatively, probably clearer in your use case, is compare with 128. Higher = white, lower = black. The result is a boolean array.

```
img_b_blue_bin = img_b_blue >= 128
```

---

Similarly, the (n+1)-th least significant bit can be found using `(x >> n) & 1`, e.g. the 2nd most significant bit:

```
img_b_blue_2nd_msb = (img_b_blue >> 6) & 1
```

the least significant bit:

```
img_b_blue_lsb = img_b_blue & 1
```

See [How am I getting a single bit from an int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21878434/how-am-i-getting-a-single-bit-from-an-int) for how this works for a single integers.

Comment: Well done. I wanted to post the `>> 7` trick, but you're right that `128` is much clearer.

Comment: thank you very much, right-shift 7 bits resolved the problem to get the most significant bit. What about to get the other bits? How can I get the middle and the last bit?